# sorting an array in javascript, such that new starting and ending items but they have the same order

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

let's say I have this array of number in reverse order:

```
var days = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
```

and I have this variable:

```
var startingDay = 4;
```

How can I sort the array so that the array is like this

```
console.log(days == [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 6, 5]);
>> true
```

??

Thanks!

Comment: That's not sorting, the array is already sorted. It's just rotating the array.

Comment: then how do I "rotate" it?

Comment: Check the duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

You can rotate the array by slicing and concatenating the two parts.

```js
var days = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
var day = 4;
var idx = days.indexOf(day);
var res = days.slice(idx).concat(days.slice(0, idx));
console.log(res);
```

You can also use `unshift` and `splice` to modify the array in-place.

```js
var days = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
var day = 4;
days.unshift(...days.splice(days.indexOf(day), days.length));
console.log(days);
```